# Check Image Cache of specific image url exist or not when using picasso image loader?

Tags: android, picasso

in my project i am using picasso image loader to display multiple images from urls,how to check Image Cache of specific image url exist or not.please give some solution.

```
Picasso.with(context).load("thumburl" 
                        .networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE) 
                        .into(photo, new Callback() {
                            @Override 
                            public void onSuccess() { 

                            } 

                            @Override 
                            public void onError() { 
                              //Try for online if no data in cached or cached failed 
                                Picasso.with(context) 
                                        .load("thumburl") 
                                .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                                .error(R.drawable.user_error)
                                        .into(photo); 
                            } 
                        });
```

Comment: Are you doing this to save traffic and load the cached image instead of downloading a fresh one?